# Condional annotations on a class in python

Tags: python, class, conditional-statements, python-decorators

Below is the code snippet I want to accomplish. Please help!

```
try:
    from cinder import interface
    interface_available = True
except ImportError:
    interface_available = False

@interface.volumedriver
class EMCCoprHDFCDriver(driver.FibreChannelDriver):
```

Now the above would give an error in case the 'interface' module is not available, i.e, interface_available = False.
However, if the 'interface' module is available, the annotation should be used above the class.

Is there any way, I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

If the decorator does not exist then simply use the identity decorator to perform a no-op:

```
try:
    from cinder.interface import volumedriver
except ImportError:
    def volumedriver(func):
        return func

@volumedriver
class EMCCoprHDFCDriver(driver.FibreChannelDriver):
```

---

Why this works:

A python decorator:

```
@decorator
def some_function:
    pass
```

is just syntactic sugar for calling:

```
some_function = decorator(some_function)
```

If we think about decorators this way, it is clear that if we want to apply a decorator that does nothing (the no-op decorator or identity decorator) we should make a decorator that returns the original function.

```
def identity(func):
    return func

@identity
def func():
    pass
```